# Git: Too many active changes issue for AWS Lambda project

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am developing a REST API with `AWS Lambda` and `Amazon API Gateway`. I am using `Node.js` for this. Also using `sam` tool for `AWS Cloud Formation`.

I am sending my code to BitBucket, which is my remote repo.

However I can see that I am getting the following issue in the local repo.

[image]

This is because of the `.aws-sam` folder which is not committed to git.

[image]

I can see for every labda function i have, the `.aws-sam` folder has created a separate folder. Not only that, in each folder, my entire project code is available. So as a result, all of my project files are duplicated in each folder making over 5000 uncommitted files. I have lot more Lambda functions to come, so the situation will be worst in future.

This is my `.gitignore` file

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/osx,node,linux,windows

### Linux ###
*~

# temporary files which can be created if a process still has a handle open of a deleted file
.fuse_hidden*

# KDE directory preferences
.directory

# Linux trash folder which might appear on any partition or disk
.Trash-*

# .nfs files are created when an open file is removed but is still being accessed
.nfs*

### Node ###
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed
*.pid.lock

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# nyc test coverage
.nyc_output

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# Bower dependency directory (https://bower.io/)
bower_components

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directories
node_modules/
jspm_packages/

# Typescript v1 declaration files
typings/

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# Optional eslint cache
.eslintcache

# Optional REPL history
.node_repl_history

# Output of 'npm pack'
*.tgz

# Yarn Integrity file
.yarn-integrity

# dotenv environment variables file
.env


### OSX ###
*.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride

# Icon must end with two \r
Icon

# Thumbnails
._*

# Files that might appear in the root of a volume
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
.VolumeIcon.icns
.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent

# Directories potentially created on remote AFP share
.AppleDB
.AppleDesktop
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items
.apdisk

### Windows ###
# Windows thumbnail cache files
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db
ehthumbs_vista.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Windows Installer files
*.cab
*.msi
*.msm
*.msp

# Windows shortcuts
*.lnk


# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/osx,node,linux,windows
```

can someone advice me,

1. Is it normal that inside `.aws-sam` the every Lambda function has a folder and inside every folder the complete set of code is available?
2. In git, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: `.gitignore` the entire folder and if it is already checked in anywhere remove it explicitly.

Comment: @luk2302: You mean like add `.aws-sam` text into `.gitignore` ?

Comment: No, probably `.aws-sam/`

Comment: @luk2302: That did work, thank you. Another thing, the `.gitignore` is not getting commited. I guess this is needed to be commited isnt it? In that case, how can i make sure it is commited?

Comment: `git add .gitignore`!?

Comment: @luk2302: I do `git add *` and it never did ?

Comment: @JustCause: if you're using a Unix-style shell, `git add *` won't add *any* dot-files. (If you're using bash, you can *change* this with a bash option; I think zsh might have one as well.) The reason is that filename glob `*` traditionally doesn't match dot-files on purpose. Git's own internal `*` expansion *does* match dot-files by default, but consider using `git add .` instead of `git add *`: this works *everywhere*.

Comment: @torek: Thanks. So `git add .` is equal to `git add *` but including the DOT files?

Comment: Technically, `git add .` is different because it passes the literal string `.` to `git add`. Running `git add *` passes something *shell-dependent* to `git add`: in CMD.EXE on Windows, it passes a literal `*` because CMD.EXE does nothing with `*`. In Unix `sh`, it passes all matching file names from your current directory: your shell did that. If there are no matching file names, however, some shells produce an error (`*: no match`) and some pass a literal `*` to Git. The first question is therefore: *who interpreted `*`?*

Comment: Once you have determined the answer to that, the second question is: *How did _____ (fill in the blank) interpret `*`?* We can't even *start* to answer that without first filling in the blank. But if we take two existing, standard blank-fillings, we can proceed. If we do, we find that when using shells, `*` usually omits the dot-files, which leads to the situation you described. It's important to remember *how we got there* though, because you may find yourself using Git on some other OS.